# 画像からテキストを抽出したい

Tags: 画像処理

ローカルに保存してある画像ファイルからテキストを抽出したいです
画像からテキストを抽出するアプリとかオンラインページとかはあるんですが
数が多いのでプログラムで一気にやりたいんですが簡単に実現する方法はないでしょうか

画像の中には短い単語１つだけがかかる状態に前処理しています
抽出するテキストは主に日本語ですが
アルファベットや数字や半角のひらがななんかもある可能性があります

---

https://github.com/tanreinama/OCR_Japanease
まず検索して出てきた python のライブラリを使ってみたんですが
使い方１２３を実行して
足りないライブラリを pip install してたんですが最終的に以下のようなエラーになります

```
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

学習済みのモデルを使うだけでもGPUが必要なんでしょうか
いずれにしてもハードウェア的な問題みたいなので諦めました

追記：

コメントでいただいた通りGPUを使わないモードがあるみたいで
サンプル画像に対しては動かすことができました

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この画像を読み込ませてみたところ
`あいうえおBC心3`
となってしまいアルファベット混じりの文字列の精度があまりよくないみたいです

---

---

https://releases.aspose.com/ocr/java/
もう１つこちらの java のライブラリも試そうとしたんですが

```
import com.aspose.ocr.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AsposeOCR api = new AsposeOCR();
        String result = api.RecognizePage("test.png");
        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

こういうテストコードをかいて aspose-ocr-22.9.jar を同じディレクトリにおいて

```
javac -classpath .\aspose-ocr-22.9.jar Test.java
java -classpath ".;.\aspose-ocr-22.9.jar" Test
```

で実行したんですが

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ai/onnxruntime/OrtException
```

という例外になってしまいます

java は学校で習ったぐらいぐらいでコマンドラインからしか使ったことがないので
クラスパスの通し方がまずいのかもしれないですが
コマンドラインから jar をリンクして使うのはどうかけばいいんでしょうか

---

---

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/google-cloud_vision-api/

こちらの記事をみながら Google Vison API というのも試してみました
キー作成してキーのJSONファイルを同じフォルダにおいて
サンプルコードの画像パスだけかえてをそのまま動かしてみたところ
以下のエラーになります

```
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

`set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="D:\orc-test\xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.json"`
を行ってから再実行してもかわりません

環境は windows10 powershell 上です

`cat "D:\orc-test\xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.json"`
を実行すると中身が表示されるのでパスは間違っていないはずです

追記：

コメントで指摘していただいた通りパワーシェルじゃなくコマンドプロンプトで実行したところAPIの結果は帰ってきました

```
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please enable billing on project #xxxxxxxx by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=xxxxxxxx then retry. If you enabled billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. [links {
```

ただ支払いがどうのこうのというエラーになって課金関連の設定までしないと使えないようです。
ただ趣味で使ってみたいだけであまり理解せずクレカ登録とかするの怖いのでまた時間あるときにドキュメント読んでから試したいと思います

---

---

言語は ruby / python / javascript(node) / C / C++ / Java
あたりで他にも簡単に使えるライブラリがあれば教えてほしいです

あるいはライブラリじゃなくてもフリーで使えるAPIとかがあれば
curl 叩くだけで使えるので紹介してもらえると嬉しいです

Comment: 最初のプログラムの[「GPU無し、又は低スペックGPUで実行する」](https://github.com/tanreinama/OCR_Japanease#gpu%E7%84%A1%E3%81%97%E5%8F%88%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%8E%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%83%83%E3%82%AFgpu%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) の内容は試しましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。今試してみたところ動きはしたんですが精度がよくなかったです。詳細は質問文に追記しました

Comment: 2番目のライブラリですが、[Recognition languages](https://docs.aspose.com/ocr/java/languages/) に日本語が見あたりません。日本語に対応していることは確認済みですか？

Comment: 3番目の API の利用ですが、PowerShell で `set` は使えるのでしょうか。私は詳しくないですが、確認してみて下さい。

Comment: なお、質問は問題ごとに分けた方が良いと思います。

Comment: わかりました。分割して質問し直します。

Comment: Java のはサポートキャラクターを見ると日本語ダメみたいですね　あまりちゃんと読んでなかったです。申し訳ありません。